# Facebook Open Graph Debugger - "Error parsing input URL" for URL with a query string

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Sharing a URL with a query string does not work on Facebook:

http://greenchef.com/?a=b

The OpenGraph debugging tool [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) returns the following error:

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.
```

What's a good way to make this work?

Comment: Works fine here. http://cl.ly/image/1H3h2D2m0L07/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-15%20at%206.16.06%20PM.png

Answer (score 0):

when the OpenGraph debugger returns this message.

```
 Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.
```

click  'Fetch new scrape information'. so that the debugger process the data in the url and save it.